# perl, system function and run external command

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying launch `adduser` command from perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @test=('/usr/sbin/useradd',
"-c 'Fred'",
'-d /vol2/home/DMZ/f.kals',
'-g 3335','-u 11002',
"-k '/dev/null'",
'-m',
'-p "$1$kKNKMa8O$g03oj6YeeZbO2i3NMSoyT1"',
'fred');
system (@test);
```

When I executed the above, I got the following output:

```
[ay@pandora /vol2]$ sudo ./test.pl
useradd: invalid home directory ' /vol2/home/DMZ/fred'
```

Why?

If I do not use array

```
my $command="/foor/bar/useradd -m -g 1234 -u 6789 -param2 -param3 username"
system ($command);
```

that works OK.. why not array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my @test=('/usr/sbin/useradd',
"-c 'Fred'",
```

1. `-c` and `Fred` are different arguments, so are `-d` and `/vol2/home/DMZ/fred` ...
2. When you use array form, you don't have to escape/quote. (this is why array form is safer -- you don't have to handle the shell escapes!)

So, it should be:

```
my @test=('/usr/sbin/useradd',
'-c', 'Fred',
'-d', '/vol2/home/DMZ/f.kals',
'-g', '3335',
'-u', '11002',
'-k', '/dev/null',
'-m',
'-p', '$1$kKNKMa8O$g03oj6YeeZbO2i3NMSoyT1',
'fred');
```

Comment: @AntonShevtsov If this answered your question, you should click the checkmark to the left to mark it as "accepted".